# How can I log my printf statements to a file to use as logging?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, logging

I have an OSX app that is mostly written in Objective-C. One piece of it though is a driver that I had to write in standard C in which I user printf states to log out debug info to the xcode console. I would like to clean these up and essentially write log statements to a file so that when the app is in the public I can have proper reporting that can be emailed out if necessary. Can I do that with the printf statement or perhaps make my own "Log" function that writes specific strings to a log file?

I use Cocoalumberjack for the Objective-C code and it works great, but cannot be used for C to my knowledge due to some of C's types.

Thanks!

Comment: `fprintf()` writes to a file. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Did not know that, thank you. Is that a practical way to log error info? I don't really have a problem at the moment I would just like to keep error logs for my driver.

Comment: Its one possibility if you need a dedicated logfile for your driver. But you should also have a look at the standard system logger (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/syslog.3.html). On OS X this is a wrapper around the "Apple System Log facility" (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html).

Comment: Appreciate it! Will take a look at this. I would definitely prefer using something standard than my own solution.

Comment: For a more sophisticated solution you should take a look at Log4Cpp: http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/